# Appium [iOS] - Couldn't launch app on simulator

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium

I had installed Appium and all necessary stuff for running of application via iOS Simulator

Then I started a simulator and launched the Appium (sure path to application was set in Settings before launching)

I don't know whether the application should be open immediately after launching or not. That's why I ran Inspector. Seems the device was connected and installation of app was started. App crashed after the launch screen was shown. I tried the same flow with another application, getting the same result. Here are logs from Appium:

```
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.73F7270E-C69E-4CF5-8586-39358163963A.launchd_sim[6364] (UIKitApplication:com.wholefoods.WholeFoods[0x7ca4][6420]): Program specified by service does not contain one of the requested architectures: �<0
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple.local SpringBoard[6378]: Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:com.wholefoods.WholeFoods[0x7ca4]': No such process (err 3)
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple.local SpringBoard[6378]: Unable to delete job with label UIKitApplication:com.wholefoods.WholeFoods[0x7ca4]. Error: Operation now in progress
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple.local SpringBoard[6378]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.wholefoods.WholeFoods[0x7ca4]' exited for an unknown reason.
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.73F7270E-C69E-4CF5-8586-39358163963A.launchd_sim[6364] (UIKitApplication:com.wholefoods.WholeFoods[0x7ca4][6420]): Trampoline was terminated before jumping to service: Killed: 9

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Failed looking up pid of launched process
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple.local DTMobileIS[6387]: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jul 24 10:29:07 MacBook-apple.local DTMobileIS[6387]: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.launchdaemon

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPad 2 (8.3 Simulator)
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPad 2 (8.3 Simulator)" /var/folders/7x/pfjm_c_s37ngl66yrs82ry3m0000gn/T/115624-6265-9ypyif/Payload/WholeFoods.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-4e580d338a12229a.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {"DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd6/InstrumentsShim.dylib","LIB_PATH":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd6"}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

blablabla

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 117025.667 ms - 182 

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, though not trivial

Once you've build the app for the simulator:

1. In Xcode at the left panel find `Products`
2. There you'll find your application. Tap it with right click (even if it is red)
3. At the right panel you'll see the path at `Full Path`. Copy it up to last element. For example seeing `/projects/.../yourproject-<bhah>/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/yourproject.app` you need: `/projects/.../yourproject-<bhah>/Build/Products`
   3.1. Or you can find it with:Tap it with right click (even if it is red) and select `show in finder`
4. Go one to the enclosing folder (`Go->Enclosing folder`)
5. Open that dir. You'll find there `Debug-iphonesimulator` and `yourproject.app` there.

that's the one you need